# Constructing a const object over itself

Tags: c++, c++20, undefined-behavior, lifetime, stdlaunder

In the following example I ended the life of `s` (by calling its dtor.), and after that at the same location I created a new object of the same type `S`. Since I violated [[basic.life]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8.3) (`s` is const), in order to access the newly created `S` I have to `std::launder` its address (see [Note 3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#note-3)).

```
#include <new>
#include <utility>

struct S {
    int x;
};

template <class T, class... Pars>
void Recreate(const T& value, Pars&&... pars) {
    value.~T();
    new(const_cast<T*>(&value)) T(std::forward<Pars>(pars)...);
}

int main() {
    const S s(1);
    Recreate(s, 2);
    return std::launder(&s)->x;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/or8fqKKoj).

Does this program have to return `1` or `2` or is it UB? Or how to `std::launder` properly? Or is it just ambiguously specified? Notes are non-normative.

Comment: You need to look a bit below at [basic.life]/10.

Comment: Thanks. [\[basic.life\]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#10) says it's UB to reuse the storage of a const automatic object. So the answer is UB.